# Python Webdriver need code to find and click a particular element

Tags: python, selenium

This is a similar question to one answered for me earlier.
I have used Python 2.7, Webdriver and Chrome to access Pinterest to insert images to a board. I have successfully logged in to the site and created a board. The problem that I have is to identify and click the “Edit Board” button successfully using xpath find elements code. I attach an image of the web page (see red arrow) and the Chrome inspect on the element. The code I have tried is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Edit board")]')
```

The result is enabled and displayed, however, click on the element gives the following exception:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable
>   at point (131, 91). Other element would receive the click: <button
>   class="Button Module ShowModalButton boardEditButton btn hasIcon
>   rounded" type="button">...</button>

I cannot see any other find element option which will make the button unique.

I have successfully used the span text find on this website in one other place. It does not work for all buttons of this type, but, in those cases another unique tag qualifier works.

Web Page:

[image: Web Page]

Inspect Element:

[image: Inspect Element]

Comment: can you share url of webpage

Comment: This page only appears in this format for the owner of the board. I suggest that you login to Pinterest create a board and navigate to a page like this one. The elements will be the same as in my example.

Comment: I found an alternative work around to this problem. With this type of exception (see above), I have found that the solution is to iterate through the elements wit a, for example, driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Edit board")]')and then verify the one that you need is clickable and then click it.